# RegEx for embedding YouTube iframe

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

PHP code:

```
$patterny = '/(.*) ((youtube.com) | (youtu.be) | (www.youtube.com)) (.*)/i';

$replacementy = '<iframe src="http://youtube.com/$6" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$string2 = preg_replace($patterny, $replacementy, $string);

echo $string2;
```

I tested the above regex in http://regex101.com and it outputs satisfactory.

https://regex101.com/r/wqbywv/1

When I look at view source for the web page that the iframe should display on I only get the below URL.

https://www.youtube.com/qvuvjEkeDAw

The iframe code is nowhere to be seen.

Each youtube link will be on its own line in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that, here we just need to add an `i` which is missing in `iframe` close tag. Also, we could modify and simplify our expression, if we wish to:

#### Test

```
$re = '/(.*) ((youtube.com) | (youtu.be) | (www.youtube.com) ) (.*)/mix';
$str = 'http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM
www.youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM
youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs
youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wtIMTCHWuI
http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3&autohide=1
http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3D-wtIMTCHWuI&format=json
Hello https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs world
';
$subst = '<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com$6" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v=-wtIMTCHWuI" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3&autohide=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/-wtIMTCHWuI" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v%3D-wtIMTCHWuI&format=json" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="htpp://youtube.com/watch?v=nzj7Wg4DAbs world" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5obctb/1)